# I wanted to fetch the data from google dashboards using Azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I wanted to fetch the data from google dashboards and load it to azure data warehouse using azure data factory.
Is there any way I can follow to load the data to data warehouse using azure data factory.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [ADF copy activity support connector list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview), there is no google dashboard connector.So,maybe you have to consider 2 ways:

1.If you could fetch data from google dashboards via REST API,then you could use [Web Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity) in ADF and connect it with Copy Activity.

2.If not,i notice that ADF supports [google could storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-google-cloud-storage).So you could try to sync your data into it and use copy activity.

Comment: Do you know Any API Which I can use to fetch the data